# PHP casting populated string as false

Tags: php, casting

So I am using some logic to check if someone searching for a client has provided enough information for the search, but for some reason, one of my strings is being cast as false in the if statement even though it has a value...

```
// get lookup parameters
$clientID = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["clientID"]);
$fistName = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
$lastName = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
$phone = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);

// check if enough parameters were provided
if (!($clientID) && !($firstName && $lastName) && !($phone)) {
    // die
    printf("Invalid search parameters.");
    exit();
}
```

When I provide a clientID or phone number there is no issue, but when using a first and last name, it enters the if.  I had it print the values of the variables inside the if and it shows $firstName = "Andrew", $lastName = "[insert my lastname]".  If I have it print them casted as bools, $firstName is true and $lastName is false.

I have no idea why it would be casting one string as true and one as false, unless it takes into account what is in the string maybe?  My last name starts as an "F".  Really flailing here and throwing out wild ideas.

Comment: Not all values are equivalent to true. But a string that starts with the letter "F" is. I suspect this is n;t the cause of your problem.

Comment: @crazypeopleruleu - You have a typo: $fistname

Comment: you should validate your input _before_ escaping it.

Comment: Actually, you should use parametrized queries so that escaping isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get lookup parameters
$clientID = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["clientID"]);
$firstName = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
$lastName = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
$phone = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);

// check if enough parameters were provided
if (!$clientID && !$firstName && !$lastName && !$phone) { //No need for all the brackets
    // die
    echo'Invalid search parameters.';//echo
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What does this solve? Edit: Right, the typo. If you're going to answer with code, at least mention what you did and why.

Comment: It solves the question. $firstName was incorrectly spelled in the question, the above corrects the misspelling = the answer.